# How to reconcile performance with dividends?

Tags: united-states, dividends, vanguard, income-statement

I have a Vanguard fund that returned -1.34% for the year, yet I earned dividends on the same investment of $106 for the same year. How do I reconcile negative performance with positive dividends?  Is there a calculation I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't identify the fund but here is the most obvious way: Some of the stocks they owned could had dividends. Therefore they would have had to pass them on to the investors.

If the fund sold shares of stocks, they could have capital gains. They would have sold stocks to pay investors who sold shares. They also could have sold shares of stock to lock in gains, or to get out of positions they no longer wanted.

Therefore a fund could have dividends, and capital gains, but not have an increase in value for the year. Some investors look at how tax efficient a fund is, before investing.

Answer (score 0):

The same as you would for an individual stock. A stock starts the year at $100, and has $4 in dividends over the year, why would the fact the the stock ends the year at say $90, confuse you?

You pay tax on the dividend at the favored rate, if held in a taxable account, obviously, and that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the published annualized returns, which are inclusive of distributions and fees.

From the [Vanguard website](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/content/Funds/FundsImportantFundInfoJSP.jsp):

> Average annual returns include changes in share price and reinvestment of dividends and capital gains.